# Is it possible to logout when the Home button is pressed?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to logout when the iPhone Home button is pressed?

Answer (score 4):

In the current iPhone API, it is impossible to "hijack" any of the hardware presses.  You will be notified of certain events however. If you are wishing to call some function (logout) when the user exits the app by pressing the home button,  you can implement the

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
....
}
```

method in your Application Delegate.  This method is called when the app is about to terminate through a phone-call, manual exit, or any other reason.  You should be advised, however, that anything here better be very short execution and non-essential, as Apple does not guarantee that it will run through the whole method before terminating the application

Comment: I think when home button is pressed one time - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application methods is called thats y - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application method must be overidden for the Jeff's desired purpose.

Comment: This is a very old answer and is no longer accurate. applicationDidEnterBackground is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 4.0 + however you will have to implement logout in this method as well

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```